Passing a promise to addEventListener() in TypeScript?
On a sveltekit app, I am trying to create an event listener that executes an async function (a mutation) using Typescript.
onMount(() => {
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyPress);
});

The argument I pass to the addEventListener is an async function defined as...
async function handleKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (mainList.length > 0) {
    const press =
      event.key === 'ArrowLeft' ? 'left' : event.key === 'ArrowRight' ? 'right' : null;
    
      if (press) {
        await moveItem(press);
      }
  }
}

You see, addEventListener expects a function that returns void, so I am getting this error:
Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected. eslint
Anyway to solve this error?

The golden rule of linting rules is if a rule is in your way, you disable it. The rules are there to help. If they cause you to do extra work you disable them (globally or just contextually).

Or if you don't want to disable linting rule you can change it to document.addEventListener('keyup', () => handleKeyPress()); though I think it's better to just disable the rule for the line.

You should not be doing this anyway; you are leaking an event listener if you don't remove it on destroy.
There are special elements for adding listeners to the document or window.
<svelte:document on:keyup={handleKeyPress} />

